# Make one command return several attributes and assign them to variables

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make a command return several attributes and then assign each attribute to a variable?

```
gwmi -computer $compname Win32_ComputerSystem | ForEach {$_.Name,$_.Domain,$_.Manufacturer,$_.Model,$_.SystemType}
```

This code returns Name, domain.. as you can see. is it possible to save for example:
$_.Name to a variable $Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a variable for each try this:

```
gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem | ForEach {$name = $_.Name; $domain = $_.Domain; $Manufacturer = $_.Manufacturer; $model = $_.Model; $systemtype =$_.SystemType}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I were looking for. Good weekend to you Sir.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention: Is there a clever way to do something similar to a command that returns several instances of the same atribute?
For example:
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | ForEach {$_.Model}
returns several model objects, then I want to place each of theese in a xml file..

Comment: Make a new question with all details of your goal!

Answer (score 1):

This will create variables for each property:

```
$cs = gwmi -computer $compname Win32_ComputerSystem 
$Name,$Domain,$Manufacturer,$Model,$SystemType = $cs.Name,$cs.Domain,$cs.Manufacturer,$cs.Model,$cs.SystemType

# print variables
$Name,$Domain,$Manufacturer,$Model,$SystemType
```

Comment: Thank you! If possible I would share the reward between you and @Christian, but his code was a little more effective. Have a nice weekend!